# Inverse function of numpy.polyval()

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering is there a convenient inverse function of np.polyval(), where I give the y value and it solves for x?

I know one way I could do this is:

```
import numpy as np

# Set up the question
p = np.array([1, 1, -10])
y = 100

# Solve
p_temp = p
p_temp[-1] -= y
x = np.roots(p_temp)
```

However my guess is most would agree on that this code has low readability. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
In [19]: p = np.poly1d([1, 1, -10])  # Use a poly1d to represent the polynomial.

In [20]: y = 100

In [21]: (p - y).roots
Out[21]: array([-11.,  10.])
```

The `poly1d` object implements the arithmetic operations to return a new `poly1d` object, so `p - y` is a new `poly1d`:

```
In [22]: p - y
Out[22]: poly1d([   1,    1, -110])
```

The `roots` attribute of a `poly1d` returns what you would expect.