# Get the inverse function of a polyfit in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I have fit a second order polynomial to a number of x/y points in the following way:

```
poly  = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
```

How can I invert this function in python, to get the two x-values corresponding to a specific y-value?

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847605/reverse-output-of-polyfit-numpy?

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749610/inverse-function-of-numpy-polyval

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example that shows how you can combine your `poly`
with my answer at [Inverse function of numpy.polyval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749610/inverse-function-of-numpy-polyval).

First some data:

```
In [44]: x
Out[44]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

In [45]: y
Out[45]: array([ 9,  4,  0, -1, -1,  4,  8, 16])
```

Fit a polynomial to the data:

```
In [46]: poly = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
```

Find where the polynomial has the value `y0`

```
In [47]: y0 = 4
```

To do that, create a `poly1d` object:

```
In [48]: p = np.poly1d(poly)
```

And find the roots of `p - y0`:

```
In [49]: (p - y0).roots
Out[49]: array([ 5.21787721,  0.90644711])
```

Check:

```
In [54]: x0 = (p - y0).roots

In [55]: p(x0)
Out[55]: array([ 4.,  4.])
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  You want to find the inverse value at 4, and your result is 2 values??

Comment: @johnktejik, yes, of course.  There are two `x` values where `p(x)` is 4.

Answer (score 2):

`np.polyfit` returns the coefficients of the best fit polynomial, highest first. Thus your `poly` contains `c2, c1, c0` and you have to solve

```
.      2
.   c x + c x + c  = y
.    2     1     0
```

The solution can be found in many places for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Answer (score 0):

Following on Warren's answer

```
    p = np.poly1d(m1)
    print(p)
    y0 = returns[sr.argmax()]
    x0 = p(y0)
    #x0 = p((p - y0).roots)
    print(x0)
    print(y0)
```