# how to calculate polynomial function in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, list

[image]

I plotted a curve of Area[x-axis] and Elevation[y-axis] by using  original data (red curve). now i have new series of elevation against this elevation I want to get new series of area values. For this I fitted 3rd order polynomial ( green curve) by using polyfit function in python.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


p= np.polyfit(area, Elv, 3)
plt.plot(area, Elv, 'r-')
plt.plot(area,np.polyval(p, area),'g----')
plt.xlabel('Area')
plt.ylabel('Elevation')
```

How can I get value of x[Area] in polynomial `f ( x ) = 3ax + 2ax + cx + d` against new series of Elevation i.e f(x) ?

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179087/get-the-inverse-function-of-a-polyfit-in-numpy?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you want to apply your polynomial to a different sequence of areas, or do you want to invert your true elevations values assuming they were generated by the polynomial instead of the true function?

Comment: @MarkSnyder I actually want to invert polynomial function to calculate the x values ['area'] with new series of y_values['Elevations']

Comment: @ALollz Thank yo for sharing this link but I couldn't understand clearly how they have two values of x against one value of yo = 4

Comment: On that example they fit a quadratic function so it has 2 possible values where it is 4. In this case you fit a third order polynomial so you may get 3 values. You would need to choose the correct one if there are multiple. If F(x) = x^2 then both 2 and -2 lead to a value of 4, for instance